# Migrate Arch from encrypt to sd-encrypt

Tags: arch-linux, luks, disk-encryption, whole-drive-encryption

I recently installed Antergos (which is basically Arch) and set it to use full disk encryption. Now, I want to migrate from `encrypt` to `sd-encrypt` because I want to be able to hibernate and I couldn't put swap partition in the same LUKS volume..

### Background

During the setup:

- I used LUKS for `/` partition and swap partition,
- because my main SSD is small, I wanted to be able to hibernate and I have 32GB of RAM I created the encrypted swap partition on the second drive,
- I mounted swap partition (as well as another encrypted EXT4 partition from the second drive) using `/etc/crypttab`.

I tested that installation works, grub let me boot into both linux and dual booted Windows, on Linux boot it decrypts and mounts both encrypted drives.

However, I was getting error about not finding disk with the UUID of a swap drive, and Arch manual confirmed that `encrypt` which I got from installer can handle only one encrypted partition during boot. If I want to handle more of them I should move to `sd-encrypt`. However, even after reading the documentation I am not certain what I have to do in order to migrate to `sd-encrypt`.

### Details

- `HOOKS="base udev autodetect modconf block keyboard keymap encrypt resume filesystems fsck"`
- `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet resume=UUID=[encrypted swap UUID]"`
- `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=cryptdevice=/dev/disk/by-uuid/[/ UUID]:Arch_crypt`
- `GRUB_ENABLE_CRYPTODISK=y`
- `/etc/crypttab`

  ```
    swap_crypt /dev/disk/by-uuid/[/ UUID] password_file luks
    data_crypt /dev/disk/by-uuid/[/ UUID] password_file luks
  ```

What else should I do after I change `encrypt` to `sd-encrypt` in `HOOKS`? Do I have to create a `/etc/crypttab.initramfs` and move `swap_crypt` there? Do I have to change `luks` to `rd.luks`? Both swap partition and / partition uses the same password, so according to the documentation both should be mounted on boot after I entered the password once, is that right? Documentation mentions `luks.*` and `rd.luks.*` params and similar - do I have to use them and if so, where should I put them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't use Grub myself (but Arch and sd-encrypt) but from my kernel options I guess you would have to transform your configuration to look like (don't forget to backup your old configuration before switching).

```
HOOKS="base systemd autodetect modconf block keyboard sd-vconsole sd-encrypt resume filesystems fsck"

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet resume=UUID=[decrypted swap UUID]" 
# I use resume=/dev/mapper/name-of-decrypted-device

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=luks.uuid=[/ encrypted UUID] luks.uuid=[swap encrypted UUID]
GRUB_ENABLE_CRYPTODISK=y

/etc/crypttab

  swap_crypt /dev/disk/by-uuid/[/ UUID] password_file luks
  data_crypt /dev/disk/by-uuid/[/ UUID] password_file luks
```

Don't forget to run `mkinitcpio -p linux` or the equivalent to regenerate your initramfs, once the modification of the HOOKS have been done. And the grub.cfg file with `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg` or something similar.

Comment: Just small note: I empirically checked that when you need to refer to `/dev/mapper/somename` you should use `luks.name=[UUID]=somename` because with sd-encrypt `crypttab` is not run.